# ASP.Net core 1.1 Angular2 PUT request throws No Access Control Origin

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

In my ASP.Net Core 1.1. backend I have enabled CORS as following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<WebAPIDataContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"));
    });
    services.AddScoped<IProfileRepository, ProfileRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IUser_TaskRepository, User_TaskRepository>();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });


}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    // global policy - assign here or on each controller
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


    app.UseMvc();

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });


}
```

From my angular2 frontend I am making POST and PUT requests. POST is successful but PUT fails giving me No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` They are:

```
  private base_url = 'http://localhost:4783/api/';

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  createProfile(profile: ProfileModel): Observable<ProfileModel[]>{

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'Profile', profile , options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  updateProfile(profile: ProfileModel, profileId: number): Observable<ProfileModel[]>{

    console.log(profile, profileId)

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    return this.http.put(this.base_url + 'Profile' + '/' + profileId, profile , options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check your debugging console if it is really the PUT that fails or if it is rather the OPTIONS request (browser-preflighting). If the OPTIONS is the problem you have to react in your backend. I'm no expert on asp.net core, but in a WebApi backend you have to do this in the global.asax.cs:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin")[0]);
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, accept"); 
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

If OPTIONS isn't your problem, doublecheck that you put the correct input into your call. If you mess up the necessary headers/parameters for the call you will often get this error (which can be very confusing).